# Retrieve specific value out of a data field

Tags: drupal, view

Below is some Views data that I would like to use. How would I render just the 'Lorem ipsum'? Thanks

```
stdClass Object
(
  [nid] =&gt; 13337
  [node_data_field_marquee_image_field_marquee_image_fid] =&gt; 7778
  [node_data_field_marquee_image_field_marquee_image_list] =&gt; 1
  [node_data_field_marquee_image_field_marquee_image_data] =&gt; a:3:{s:11:"description";s:11:"Lorem ipsum";s:3:"alt";s:0:"";s:5:"title";s:0:"";}
  [node_language] =&gt; 
  [node_type] =&gt; article
  [node_vid] =&gt; 22670
  [node_data_field_marquee_url_field_marquee_url_url] =&gt; www.google.com
  [node_data_field_marquee_url_field_marquee_url_title] =&gt; 
  [node_data_field_marquee_url_field_marquee_url_attributes] =&gt; a:1:{s:6:"target";s:6:"_blank";}
)
```

Render data:

```
$item = unserialize($data->node_data_field_marquee_image_field_marquee_image_data);
$description = $item['description'];
print $description;

$item2 = unserialize($data->node_data_field_marquee_url_field_marquee_url_attributes);
$target = item2['target'];
print $target;
```

Giving this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /sites/all/modules/contrib/views_customfield/includes/views_customfield_handler_field_phpcode.inc(118) : eval()'d code on line 9

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your variable is called `$node_data_field_marquee_image_field_marquee_image_data`:

```
$description = $node_data_field_marquee_image_field_marquee_image_data['description'];
```

**UPDATE**

My bad the array is serialised, you'll want to do this:

```
$item = unserialize($data->node_data_field_marquee_image_field_marquee_image_data);
$description = $item['description'];
```

Comment: The variable is $data. I'm using "Customfield: PHP Code" to render the output of the view.

I tried $description = $data->node_data_field_marquee_image_field_marquee_image_data['description']; but it did not work.

Comment: $data->node_data_field_marquee_image_field_marquee_image_data['description'] resulted in "a" being printed.

Comment: @allanb:Answer updated above, the string is serialised so you'll need to de-serialise it.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to print 2 values, the first is fine when it alone, but when I add the code to display the second value, it throws the error (edited original question)